# App keeps getting rejected due to Guideline 5.2.2 - Legal: Intellectual Property - Third Party Sites/Services

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

In my app, I am using an unofficial Instagram API (https://www.instagram.com/id/?__a=1) in order to retrieve Instagram contents such as photos and videos, load, and repost them through the app.

Apple has been getting rejected the app stating the following:

> Guideline 5.2.2 - Legal
>
> Your app contains content or features that may violate the rights of
> one or more third parties. Specifically, your app requests, displays,
> or distributes third-party account information in order to allow
> unauthorized access to said service.
>
> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of
> another party. In the event, your app infringes another party’s rights,
> you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App
> Review Information section in App Store Connect evidencing that you
> have all necessary rights or permissions to request, display, or
> distribute account information in your application. In accordance with
> section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you
> acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can
> result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and
> the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once we have reviewed
> your documentation and confirmed its validity, we will proceed with
> the review of your app.

Yesterday, I uploaded [this Facebook Developer Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/devpolicy) but I got rejected again this morning for the same guideline. Is there any way that would help me to solve that issue? What document should I provide?

Comment: Probably because of item 9.5 (in the link you provided) "Don't use the Instagram Platform to simply display User Content, import or backup content, or manage Instagram relationships, without our prior permission." I don't know exactly what permissions come with the "unofficial" api

Comment: @SanzioAngeli Any idea what should I do next? Apple has been helpful on their end.

Comment: I would do what they suggest if you have talked with someone and they recommended something

Comment: This looks to be a customer service question not a programming question, which would be off-topic here.  Please see: [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) and [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal compliance / customer support question, not a programming question.